How to Ensure Tree Shaking for Screen-Specific Code in Flutter?
Details
I'm building an embedded Linux Flutter app, and in this embedded world, every byte counts, especially when dealing with OTA updates over a metered network.
The app I'm building will run on multiple screen sizes, and I want to avoid having conditional statements for different screen sizes, like "if X size then use this padding" or "if X size then use this color", etc. Instead, I want each page to be specifically coded for each size. Since the screens are static (physically) and will never change or change orientation, I can tailor the UI for each specific screen size.
I’m exploring ways to ensure that some files are tree-shaken because I don't need both a 7InchDisplayHomePage() and a 15InchDisplayHomePage() in the same build. Only one of them will ever be used on the specific hardware it runs on. Here’s what I’m thinking:
I could use different main entry points for different builds, like:
flutter-elinux build elinux -t lib/main_7inch.dart --release
flutter-elinux build elinux -t lib/main_15inch.dart --release

In each main_XXinch.dart, I could define:

typedef HomePage = XXInchDisplayHomePage;


void main() {
  runApp(...);
}


And in my app I would only ever use the HomePage().
My Questions:

Do you think this "trick" could help in tree-shaking the classes I don't use?
Are there better or more efficient ways to ensure that only the necessary screen-specific code is included in the build?
How can I verify that the unused code is actually being tree-shaken in the build?

Any insights or suggestions from the community and other Flutter developers would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Haven't tried anything yet, I'm not sure how to check if things were actually tree-shaken or not.

Ok, so if I understand you correct, you will be able to determine at build time which widgets should be used? Then using different main.dart files could be the best approach
Not sure though if you can use a typedef to create a new object.

thinking further, if you use a static const flag to determine which widget a potential root widget will return from its build function, the linker should be able to remove the widget classes that are not used.

alternatively just pass a different HomeScreenWidget type to runApp() in your different main.dart files.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Thomas, thank you for your imputs, I think the last one of changing the runApp() wouldn't work since I have some screens that can be shared and others that can't and specifying this just from the widget passed to runApp() method would be difficult.
For the static const variable to define it, I wouldn't personally mind it but if someone wants to grab my repo and compile for a specific device, then they would have to change code before building and I don't want that...

what about defining different "Widget Factory" functions that in different dart files and include the correct one in different main files?
